# MOSFET N-Channel - RCD051N20

Tags: mosfet

I have designed this circuit that outputs 7 or 28 mA depending is the MOSFET is closed or open. The gate of the MOSFET is controlled with an Analog Output from a DAQ that jumps between 0 and 10V.
However, there is a leakage current during the transition OFF-ON state of the MOSFET that flows from the DAQ into the main circuit. Is there a way to avoid this flow of current during the transition OFF-ON? I believe this leakage current is caused by the capacitance between the gate and the source of the MOSFET.

[image]

Comment: I've had a quick look at the [data sheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/lm234.pdf) for the LM134/234/334 and note that it is highly temperature sensitive, in fact they recommend it for use as a possible temperature probe. Have you taken this into account? You might want to look at Page 8 fig 14. Also the exact current it will pass with a 10 ohm Rset needs to be calibrated on an individual basis as the formula is only approximate. the current ratio can vary between 14 and 26, see page  3 "Electrical Characteristics".

Comment: Why do you think the excess current is coming through the gate of the transistor? I'd start by evaluating the performance of those LM334's. Might take some time before stabilizing their current regulation.

Answer (score 0):

IRLR024 has 870pF gate-source capacitance, so when the driver raises gate voltage from 0V to +10V this will inject a charge q=CV=8.7nC into the output. The resulting current is inversely proportional to switching time.

To prevent this, you can use a MOSFET with much lower capacitance. Since RdsON isn't critical in this application, a FET with RdsON of a few ohms and Cg of a few pF should solve the problem.

As others have said LM324 current depends strongly on temperature, so this won't be very accurate. The [datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/lm234.pdf) also shows its transient response and output impedance. When turning on, it will need about 200µs to settle, during which output current will be very inaccurate. If you need faster switching and quick settling (or temperature stability), then this isn't the chip for the job.

If you want to design a current source that can be switched between two different currents, please ask a new question and specify accuracy, temperature drift, switching time, settling time, etc.