# TLE5046iC - Emulator

Tags: current-source

I would like to ask the StackExchange community what would be the best way to emulate this sensor ([TLE5046iC](https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/sensor/magnetic-sensors/magnetic-speed-sensors/tle5046ic-ak-lr/)). I have used the LM334M to emulate it but it has some [drawbacks](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/605230/mosfet-n-channel-rcd051n20/605246#605246). One of them is that the current largely depends on the temperature of the IC. The other one is slow, where it takes about 10us to fully transient from 0 -> 7 mA.

Ideally, I would like to have a similar setup to the one designed before where I control the voltage gate in the MOSFET with an Analog Output of my DAQ.

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is the current pulses (seen in chapter 4 of the datasheet) that are sent by the sensor when a magnetic threshold is surpassed.

Answer (score 1):

The sensor does not produce `the current pulses (seen in chapter 4 of the datasheet) that are sent by the sensor when a magnetic threshold is surpassed`. Technically speaking, the transmitter located at the sensor side is a controlled current source. Ultimately, you want to built a loop-powered transmitter circuit.

The two-wire current interface of TLE5046iC is an extension of 'classical' 4-20mA current loop transmitter: the signals `Current level for indicating errors` \$I_{Error} = 3.5\text {mA}\$ and `Supply current during static output high state (AK)` \$I_{high} = 28\text {mA}\$ lie outside the 4-20mA current range ([TLE5046iC data sheet](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-TLE5046_AK_PWM2_wheel_speed_sensor-DataSheet-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d46272e49d2a01730f0a90b229f5), page 5/14, table 4). Notice also that the protocol uses only four predetermined current levels, \$I_{Error},\,I_{low},\,I_{mid},\,I_{high}\$, and it is a good news for you, because you can do without DAC.

For your emulator, you can try and repeat the design of industrial current loop transmitter, as it is presented, for example, in Maxim Integrated's application note [REFERENCE SCHEMATIC 5610](https://pdfserv.maximintegrated.com/en/an/REFD5610.pdf), with necessary accommodations for the extended current range. In addition, I recommend you to read Texas Instrument's application note ***[Loop-powered 4- to 20-mA transmitter circuit](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slaa866/slaa866.pdf?ts=1643010428569)*** and especially carefully study the document [Reference design overview and verified performance test data](https://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/tiduam6) from the page https://www.ti.com/tool/TIDA-00648. In the latter document, pay attention to the warning: do not replace the NPN BJT with an N-channel field-effect transistor (FET) (page 11/27, just above the section ***4.2 Power Design***). Remember, that four discrete levels of the AK signaling significantly simplify the design in your application as compared to cited documents, where the 4-20mA range is used to map the continuous signal from sensors. You can comfortably relax stringent requirements to current value errors. The discrete current values of AK protocol only have to be within quite wide tolerance ranges \$1 < I_{Error} < 3.8;\,5.95 < I_{low} < 8.05;\,11.9 < I_{mid} < 16.1;\,23.8 < I_{high} <32.2\$

Infineon's [TLE5041plusC book Wheel Speed Sensor](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-TLE5041PLUSC-DataSheet-v01_02-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d46265f064ff016632437f574f75) gives a general insight into operation of integrated giant magneto resistive
(GMR) elements.